# HAML error in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm trying to execute the following command:

```
 rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=development
```

But its resulting in some nasty errors, which I think, are related to the haml gem:

```
   rake aborted!
NameError: undefined method `precompiled_method_return_value' for class `Haml::Compiler'
/vagrant/b2c/config/environment.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:abort_if_pending_migrations => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm running this on a VM with vagrant and VirtualBox. Any ideas what could be causing this error? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has this problem: i solved it by setting up an other virtual machine. The box, that was causing the problem, was a precise64 (Ubuntu Version 14.04). Now i am using the bento/ubuntu 16.04 box and it all works fine.
Hope it helps anyone !

Answer (score 1):

it can be a bug in ruby or in the haml gem. It seems like you are using ruby 2.3.1 but, what versión of the haml gem are you using?.

You can find a similar error in the haml issues tracker https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/909, but is related to ruby version 2.4.

Ricardo.

Comment: I am using haml version 5.0.1 and ruby version 2.3.1 , that's correct! You mean switching to ruby Version 2.4 may fix the bug? The error from the issue tracker seems to be fixed by a haml update